# No Tab Bash Auto-Complete for apt in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, 14.04

Now Ubuntu 14.04 is released and I upgraded my system a few days ago. One major change was the introduction of a new version of apt. Fortunately, it is possible to do the most common task by just writing `apt` and the necessary command e.g. `install`.

Unfortunately, there is still one feature missing from the older apt-get: Auto-Complete. When I type `sudo apt` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it suggestes all files in my current directory. Also, if I type `sudo apt install dcon` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, nothing happens. Doing the same with `sudo apt-get install dcon` will invoke the suggestions to install different packages beginning with `dconf`.

Is there a possibility to enable the auto-complete in `apt`?

Comment: I do not think there is apt. what do you get if you type `sudo apt` as output?

Comment: If I press TAB behind the apt, I get recommendations for programs beginning with apt. If I press TAB after a space, I get all files in my current directory.

Comment: in the list of suggested program with TAB, there is apt? I mean only apt, not the commands that begin with apt-. I'm pretty sure that if you try to run the command `sudo apt` give back an error like: `sudo apt: command not found`

Comment: Yes, this is a change in ubuntu 14.04

Comment: sorry, I did not know: I'm still at 13:10. I searched in launchpad  and i find [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/apt) but I do not see the command apt anyway